# convert simple callbacks into async await

Tags: node.js, express

I am finding it hard to convert this user controllers code to async await. Can someone please help and guide me how can i do it too. So that i can also change any callbacks into async await.
Also if someone can provide a good source so that i can read about async await and how to apply them properly.

```
const User = require("../models/user")

exports.getUserById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    User.findById(id).exec((error, user) => {
        if (error || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "No user was found in DB"
            })
        }
        req.profile = user
        next()
    })
}

exports.getUser = (req, res) => {
    req.profile.salt = undefined;
    req.profile.encrypted_password = undefined;

    return res.json(req.profile)
}

exports.getAllUsers = (req, res) => {
    User.find().exec((error, users) => {
        if (error || !users) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "No users was found in DB"
            })

        }

        return res.json(users)
    })
}

exports.updateUser = (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(

        { _id: req.profile._id },
        { $set: req.body },
        { new: true, useFindAndModify: false },
        (error, user) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "You are not authorized to update this info"
                })
            }
            user.salt = undefined;
            user.encrypted_password = undefined;
            res.json(user)
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like this:

```
const User = require("../models/user");

exports.getUserById = async (req, res, next, id) => {
  let user = await User.findById(id);
  try {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: "No user was found in DB"
      });
    }
    req.profile = user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: "Something went wrong"
    });
  }
};

exports.getUser = (req, res) => {
  req.profile.salt = undefined;
  req.profile.encrypted_password = undefined;

  return res.json(req.profile);
};

exports.getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
  let users = await User.find();
  try {
    if (users.length < 1) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        error: "No users was found in DB"
      });
    }
    return res.json(users);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: "Something went wrong"
    });
  }
};

exports.updateUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.profile._id },
      { $set: req.body },
      { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }
    );

    user.salt = undefined;
    user.encrypted_password = undefined;
    return res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: "You are not authorized to update this info"
    });
  }
};
```

You should send back `404` errors if you cant find any user in the database. `400` means bad request.

Comment: i dont think we can use exec if we are using async await

Comment: @ABHISHEKBARTHWAL yea, remove it

Comment: @lfaruki  can you suggest any source from where i can learn

Comment: @ABHISHEKBARTHWAL blogs, tutorials, private projects. most important is to have a solid understanding of javascript. and also read the documentation https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find they have done it with `await` too in their small example

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are asking by wrapping the function with Promise. In your example, you should use the solution given by Ifaruki, because mongoose already supports promises.

```
function waitSeconds(seconds) {
  return new Promise(res => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       res();
     }, seconds * 1000)
  })
}

async function foo() {
  console.log("Hello");
  await waitSeconds(5);
  console.log("World");
}
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) you can learn more about async in javascript